# Why does assignment not work the same in Dart as it does in Python?

Tags: dart, assign

When I run this code:

```
void readCard(db, [int card_id = -1]) {
    if (card_id == -1) {
        final ResultSet result = db.select('SELECT * FROM cards');
    }

    else {
        final ResultSet result = db.select("""
                SELECT * FROM cards
                WHERE card_id=(?)
                """); // this doesn't work yet
    }

    for (final Row card in result) {
        print(
                "Card {'card_id': ${card['card_id']}, "
                "'due': ${card['due']}, "
                "'content': ${card['content']}}"
                );
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
memotext.dart:66:25: Error: Getter not found: 'result'.
        for (final Row card in result) {
                               ^^^^^^
```

Because `result` is assigned regardless of whether the if statement or the the else statement runs shouldn't there be no error? Is this something to do with the way dart does assignment?

Comment: I'm pretty sure both of the `result` is scoped to their block and doesn't exist after the block https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lexical-scope

Comment: Pardon me everyone for the stupid question. I am used to Python which appears to be dynamically scoped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is declared in their respective blocks, it doesn't exist outside. Do this:

```
void readCard(db, [int card_id = -1]) {
    ResultSet result;
    if (card_id == -1) {
        result = db.select('SELECT * FROM cards');
    }

    else {
        result = db.select("""
                SELECT * FROM cards
                WHERE card_id=(?)
                """); // this doesn't work yet
    }

    for (final Row card in result) {
        print(
                "Card {'card_id': ${card['card_id']}, "
                "'due': ${card['due']}, "
                "'content': ${card['content']}}"
                );
    }
}
```